# Length-constant password comparison in scrypt?

Tags: passwords, hash, bcrypt, scrypt, timing-attack

E.g.: XORing the candidate against stored then comparing against 0.

Do I need to worry?

(my question is much in the same style as this question: [Does bcrypt compare the hashes in "length-constant" time?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/46212))

Comment: @TerryChia: I already referenced that question. My question is about **s**crypt, not **b**crypt.

Comment: And which part of the accepted answer isn't clear? No, timing attacks aren't really relevant to hashing.

Comment: @AT My answer on that question applies to Scrypt as well

Comment: Scrypt itself has far worse timing issues internally. Unlike timing issues with comparison those might actually give an advantage to an attacker in some situations.