# Any problems with scrypt yet?

Tags: passwords, hash, scrypt

In the question [Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage) [Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415/5518) recommends the hashing function [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) but saying it is "too new to be recommended on a general basis".

Scrypt is from 2009 and I would like to know, if any problems have been found with this function, yet?

Also I would like to know if it's ready for production but I guess that would be opinion based and should only be a side note.

Comment: From [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.crypt/Wz1hzyZECKs/g6qGHLmPUPYJ) it seems scrypt is demonstrably secure.  A better question might be: is there a secure implementation out there?

Comment: There are some time-memory trade-offs that can be annoying (GPU pulls ahead of CPU) for low memory instantiations of scrypt. I'm not aware of anything that causes problems for scrypt using a lot of memory.

Comment: Pornin also said in [this very good answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) that if it's been in existence for at least 5 years, it's good, which means you could actually start using it as early as 2014 :). So if you trust him (like I do), go for it.

Answer (score 4):

After 5 month without answer, only comments, I like to sum up:

- From a discussion in [sci.crypt](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.crypt/Wz1hzyZECKs/g6qGHLmPUPYJ) it seems that scrypt is demonstrably secure.
- Most people on SO [trusts scrypt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846).
- I have seen no one claimed to have a problem with the algorithm itself.

Regardless there might be issues with the implementation. A straight forward implementation of scrypt is potentially vulnerable to timing attacks but that [should](https://github.com/pbhogan/scrypt/issues/18) [not](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46212/does-bcrypt-compare-the-hashes-in-length-constant-time) be a problem.